# Capturing data in JS from hundreds of HTML elements with unpredictable IDs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm struggling with getting data from a div in PHP to process in an external JavaScript file.

In a PHP file I have a while-loop that generates, from a DB, a lot of HTML divs (up to 250 records at a time) with various values from the DB inside them. For each div/record there is a button so people can copy one specific value to their clipboard.

My problem is that I can’t select the value by ID as that is different and unpredictable for each element.

PHP simulation for testing purposes:

```
<?php
    
    // Simulate a loop
    echo '<div class="item_bio">';
        $value = uniqid();  // A randomly generated value to simulate the value we get from the DB
        echo '<span>'.$value.'<button class="buttons value_copy_button" id="'.$value.'" data-valuetocopy="'.$value.'">Copy</button></span>';
    echo '</div>';
    
    echo '<hr>';
    
    echo '<div class="item_bio">';
        $value = uniqid();  // A randomly generated value to simulate the value we get from the DB
        echo '<span>'.$value.'<button class="buttons value_copy_button" id="'.$value.'" data-valuetocopy="'.$value.'">Copy</button></span>';
    echo '</div>';
    // End of simulated loop
    
    echo '<script src="./assets/scripts/copy_value_to_clipboard_tester.js"></script>';

?>
```

JavaScript in copy_value_to_clipboard_tester.js:

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", copyToClipboard);
      function copyToClipboard() {
        window.focus() // Focus the window to make sure writing to the clipboard is allowed
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.getElementById('copyValue').dataset.valuetocopy).then()
}
```

The challenge, and the reason I’m using an external JS file, is that I can’t use inline JavaScript because of the Content Security Policy (CSP) on the site that doesn’t allow any inline JS. That means I can’t use onclick with the unique value as I would normally have done.

How do I capture that $value from the button that was clicked if there are potentially hundreds of buttons with unpredictable IDs on the page?

Comment: The browser will pass an `Event` as the first argument to whatever function is defined as the `click` handler. If you change your function signature to `function copyToClipboard(e)`, you should be able to determine the exact button that was clicked by looking at `e.target`.

Comment: Random id values are not very useful, as you have discovered.

Comment: @Pointy Ha! Random id values are hilariously useless but I used them in my example to make clear that the ids are absolutely unpredictable from the perspective of a JS process and therefore can't be part of the usual solutions.

Answer (score 3):

2 things.

You can select any element with `querySelectorAll` function using any CSS selector. Don't have to be `id`.

And once you attach the `click` event and it is triggered by a click, you can detect the originating element using `ev.target` parameter.

```js
var foo_click = function(ev) {
  var elem = ev.target
  console.log(elem.innerText)
}

// simple, 4 handlers
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', foo_click)
})

// efficient, 1 handler for the parent element
document.querySelectorAll(".container").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', foo_click)
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>a</button>
  <button>b</button>
  <button>c</button>
  <button>d</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was just the nudge in the right direction that I needed. I've got it working now on the selector for button. I'm thinking of eventually going for a getElementsByClassName on the value_copy_button to target only those buttons more narrowly but that is not urgent right now.

Comment: it is discouraged to use `getElementsByClassName`. really the only selecting functions you need are `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector`. specifically to select by class you can `document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');`

Comment: Great, thanks again! Implemented that and works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use event delegation to handle the clicks you are looking for.

On any common ancestor of the buttons (`document.body` used below, but use a more specific container if you have one) add an event handler to respond to buttons that have the class "`value_copy_button`" - individual event handlers are not then needed. Example:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const button = event.target.closest("button");
  if(button?.classList.contains("value_copy_button")) {
    copyToClipBoard(button.dataset.valueTocopy);
  }
});
```

For this particular code example you would also change `copyToClipBoard` to take a single *string* argument, not a reference to the button clicked.

Note the `event.target.closest('button')` code is to allow any [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#technical_summary) for button elements, not just plain text, ... and no id values need to be generated for the button elements.